# pygame.midi High CPU usage

Tags: python, pygame, midi

While using pygame.midi, Python consumes 20-25% of my CPU.

I guess it's because of the "While" loop which waits for MIDI input...

Any ideas? I'd appreciate any advice you might have...

Here is the loop:

```
    going = True
    while going:
        events = event_get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type in [pg.QUIT]:
                going = False
            if e.type in [pg.KEYDOWN]:
                going = False
            if e.type in [pygame.midi.MIDIIN]:
                if e.data2 == 127:
                    shortcuts(e.data1)

        if i.poll():
            midi_events = i.read(10)
            # convert them into pygame events.
            midi_evs = pygame.midi.midis2events(midi_events, i.device_id)

            for m_e in midi_evs:
                event_post(m_e)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can limit the CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock):

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
going = True
while going:
    clock.tick(60)

    # [...]
```

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time.